# Need to Display the Data like Below format using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, cursor

If I join two tables I will get the below table

```
SELECT a.Category, a.categoryid, b.parentid,b.Level
FROM a JOIN b ONa.CatId=b.Catid
```

**Actual Data:-**

```
  Category               Catid         ParentID      Level
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  Pumps & Accss             20               0           0                                            
  Inground Pumps           213               20          1
  Above Ground             215               20          1                                              
  Commercial Pumps         216               20          1 
  Hawrd super pumps        814               213         2 
  Hywrd north pumps        815               213         2
```

This is an example one using cursor I have to apply like this for all Category Id's...

I need to display this data like this:

```
  Cat1               Cat2           Cat3             ItemNo
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  Pumps & Accss      Above Ground   Hawrd super      AX007123 
  Pumps & Accss      Above Ground   Hywrd north      AX0071201 
  Pumps & Accss      Commercial Pu  Hawrd super      AX007754  
  Pumps & Accss      Commercial Pu  Hawrd super      AX0077891 
  Pumps & Accss      Inground Pumps Hywrd north      AX0071251
```

Level 1 in Cat1 column and Level2 in Cat2 column like this i

need to get the output. like this I have 10 levels kindly post some    good answer to 
resolve this.

Comment: I think you need a PIVOT: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Any Idea about this Friends ?

Comment: cant u use join with table containing itemno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this... you can use multiple time the same table to build a multi level join

```
declare @category table(categoryId int, category char(100), principalId int)
declare @article table(articleId int, article varchar(100), categoryId int)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (1,'One', null)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (2,'two', null)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (11,'eleven', 1)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (21,'twenty one', 2)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (22,'twenty two', 2)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (111,'one hundred eleven', 11)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (211,'two hundred eleven', 21)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (221,'two hundred twenty one', 22)

insert into @category(categoryId, category, principalId)
values (2211,'two thousand two hundred twenty one', 221)

insert into @article(articleId, article, categoryId)
values (1, 'Article 1', 111)

insert into @article(articleId, article, categoryId)
values (2, 'Article 2', 211)

insert into @article(articleId, article, categoryId)
values (3, 'Article 3', 221)

insert into @article(articleId, article, categoryId)
values (4, 'Article 4', 2211)

select coalesce(c5.category,'') c5,
    coalesce(c4.category,'') c4,
    coalesce(c3.category,'') c3,
    coalesce(c2.category,'') c2,
    coalesce(c1.category,'') c1,
    a.article
from @article a
    left join @category c1 on c1.categoryId = a.categoryId
    left join @category c2 on c2.categoryId = c1.principalId
    left join @category c3 on c3.categoryId = c2.principalId
    left join @category c4 on c4.categoryId = c3.principalId
    left join @category c5 on c5.categoryId = c4.principalId
```

if you share the tables definition it helps to improve my answer, 
hope it help yo to point in the right direction

Comment: ItemNo  is there on Product Table it will read till the last child, the last level has the relationship with ItemNo table.

Comment: I used the definition of product as: declare @article table(articleId int, article varchar(100), categoryId int), as i get from you, your data is: product(productId int, itemNo varchar(x), categoryId int)... the idea is the same, just change the names of the table... the levels info is in the category table

Comment: In my Row if i have empty cell values how to remove  that ?

Comment: Friend kindly refer this url:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781309/move-cells-left-in-sql-if-left-contains-null-and-right-contains-value  I need the result on that format