# move cells left in sql if left contains null and right contains value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In Sql  I am getting the result like below format.
Totally i have 6 columns. in 1st row 6th column contains the value and 2nd row 5th & 6th contains the value. But i need to check the every cells if previous column doesn't contain the value means i need that in 1st column.

**Actual Result**

```
         a          b           c       d          e    f
                                                        1
                                                   1    2
                                        1          2    3
```

**Expected Result:-**

```
      a          b           c       d          e    f
      1                                             
      1          2                                        
      1          2           3
```

Kindly post some Good answers (I am using SQL server 2008-R2)

Comment: Any effort on your part? :) Have you tried anything yet? If so, post what you've attempted.

Comment: I'm trying Cursor for each row...  If previous column contains an empty value this will update on there.

Comment: Care to post that work? You will increase your odds at getting more and/or better help that way.

Comment: give ur sample code @Ramesh

Comment: Friends any Idea about This?

Comment: select coalesce(c6.pro,'') pro6,
coalesce(c5.pro,'') pro5,
    coalesce(c4.pro,'') pro4,
    coalesce(c3.pro,'') pro3,
    coalesce(c2.pro,'') pro2,
    coalesce(c1.pro,'') pro1,P.catalogitemno AS PRODUCT    
from Product P join  Product Cat a on p.ProductID=a.productid
    left join Cat c1 on c1.catyId = a.categoryId 
    left join Cat c2 on c2.catyId = c1.Parent
    left join Cat c3 on c3.catyId = c2.Parent
    left join Cat c4 on c4.catyId = c3.Parent
    left join Cat c5 on c5.catyId = c4.Parent
    left join Cat c6 on c6.catyId = c5.Parent                    My code is above..

Comment: If we tried this below code we can get the answer in single string, but i need like as a column by column.                                                                            SELECT ISNULL(Col1+CHAR(9),'')
      + ISNULL(Col2+CHAR(9),'')
      + ISNULL(Col3+CHAR(9),'')
      + ISNULL(Col4+CHAR(9),'')
   FROM @Test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way, similar to @Astander's (but using `OUTER APPLY` instead of `PIVOT / UNPIVOT`):

```
SELECT
    a = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 1 THEN y.val END),
    b = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 2 THEN y.val END),
    c = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 3 THEN y.val END),
    d = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 4 THEN y.val END),
    e = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 5 THEN y.val END),
    f = MIN(CASE WHEN y.rn = 6 THEN y.val END)
FROM t
  OUTER APPLY
    ( SELECT
          x.val,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rn)
      FROM
      ( VALUES 
        (a,1), (b,2), (c,3), (d,4), (e,5), (f,6)
      ) x (val, rn) 
      WHERE x.val IS NOT NULL
    ) y 
GROUP BY 
    t.tid ;
```

Test in **[SQL-FIddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/65b88b/1)**

Comment: Here I'm getting distinct values only... In my table if i need to get some repeated rows non-distinct means what i need to do?

Comment: I resolved it... Group by all the names,a,b,c,,d,e,f,g,h... Then will get the answer... Really thanks all of your effort Friends...

Comment: Could you give some explanation about this post pls? B'coz it could be very useful to all.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  i put it in SQL and it cannot recognize identifier 't'.

Comment: @JaedenRuiner `t` is the name of the table.

Comment: 9 years later you helped me out,  thank you!

Answer (score 3):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        a INT,
        b INT,
        c INT,
        d INT,
        e INT,
        f INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
(null,null,null,null,null,10),
(null,null,null,null,10,20),
(null,null,null,10,20,30)

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table

SELECT  SUM([1]) a,
        SUM([2]) b,
        SUM([3]) c,
        SUM([4]) d,
        SUM([5]) e,
        SUM([6]) f
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ValID
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  *,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ID
                        FROM    @Table
                    ) p
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                        val FOR col IN (a,b,c,d,e,f)
                    ) up
        ) v
        PIVOT (
            SUM(val) FOR ValID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
        ) p
GROUP BY    ID
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27320)

Comment: Thanks but my values are varchar,due to that SUM operend is not working?

Comment: Just change all the SUMs to MAX

Comment: Superb Lesson for Begineers