# Move cells Left if left column contains null and right column is not null

Tags: sql

Refer this Url and give some idea about this?

[move cells left in sql if left contains null and right contains value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781309/move-the-empty-cell-values-in-sql)

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Refer:-\http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781309/move-cells-left-in-sql-if-left-contains-null-and-right-contains-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        a INT,
        b INT,
        c INT,
        d INT,
        e INT,
        f INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
(null,null,null,null,null,10),
(null,null,null,null,10,20),
(null,null,null,10,20,30)

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table

SELECT  SUM([1]) a,
        SUM([2]) b,
        SUM([3]) c,
        SUM([4]) d,
        SUM([5]) e,
        SUM([6]) f
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ValID
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  *,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) ID
                        FROM    @Table
                    ) p
                    UNPIVOT
                    (
                        val FOR col IN (a,b,c,d,e,f)
                    ) up
        ) v
        PIVOT (
            SUM(val) FOR ValID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6])
        ) p
GROUP BY    ID
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/27320)

Comment: If the value is varchar() what to do?