# SQL moving data along columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have no idea where to even start with this, but here's what i need to do...

We have a table with addresses and telephone numbers in. But i need to reduce the 6 telephone number columns from 6 to 3. Moving the numbers along from right to left, into any empty cells.

Example below -

**What the table looks like**
[image: What the table looks like]

**What i want it to look like**
[image: What i want it to look like]

Comment: You need this in select, or you want to update the data?

Comment: What's your database? What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In the SELECT if possible

Comment: And its SQL Server 2012

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781309/move-cells-left-in-sql-if-left-contains-null-and-right-contains-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` will be able to do the job. The idea:

1. `UNPIVOT` to get the data into rows
2. Clean out empty rows and calculate what the new column will be
3. `PIVOT` to get the cleaned data back into columns.

Here's one way of doing it using a bunch of CTEs in one statement. Note I've assumed there is an ID column and I've made up the table name:

```
;WITH Unpivoted AS
(
    -- our data into rows
    SELECT ID, TelField, Tel
    FROM Telephone
    UNPIVOT
    (
        Tel FOR TelField IN (TEL01,TEL02,TEL03,TEL04,TEL05,TEL06)
    ) as up
),
Cleaned AS
(
    -- cleaning the empty rows
    SELECT
        'TEL0' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TelField) AS VARCHAR) [NewTelField],
        ID,
        TelField,
        Tel
    FROM Unpivoted
    WHERE NULLIF(NULLIF(Tel, ''), 'n/a') IS NOT NULL
),
Pivoted AS
(
    -- pivoting back into columns
    SELECT ID, TEL01, TEL02, TEL03
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, NewTelField, Tel
        FROM Cleaned
    ) t
    PIVOT
    (
        -- simply add ", TEL04, TEL05, TEL06" if you want to still see the
        -- other columns (or if you will have more than 3 final telephone numbers)
        MIN(Tel) FOR NewTelField IN (TEL01, TEL02, TEL03)
    ) pvt
)
SELECT * FROM Pivoted
ORDER BY ID
```

That will shift the telephone numbers into their correct place in one go. You can also change the `Pivoted` in `SELECT * FROM Pivoted` to any of the other CTEs - `Unpivoted`, `Cleaned` - to see what the partial results would look like. Final result:

[image: Results]

Comment: Without sounding stupid where do you get the columns Number and Tel from? or are you just using as an example.

Comment: `Number` was the name of unpivoted the TEL01-06 fields. `Tel` is the value in those fields. I've changed the script to instead say `TelField` to make it a bit clearer. The TechNet library has more information on how to structure a `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` query. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Cheers Balah, your explanation is spot on! And thanks for the solution, it works a treat.

Comment: This is great. Solved my hours of research. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this, the best choice depends on the database engine you're using, and/or what other tools are available.

The dirtiest method might be to write 64 different sql statements fetching out the data in each of the 64 possible combinations (including where 6 fields are all blank, and 6 fields are all populated) However, you might not relish this in practice.

So the problem is finding a simple, repeatable algorithm to reduce the problem space to something simpler.

One way to do this is to write 6 statements, each of which performs, where possible, a shift, to the left of one space.

e.g.

```
update table set field1 = field2, field2 = null from table
where field2 is not null and field1 is null
```

Moves content from field2 into field 1, if and only if field1 is blank, and field 2 is not blank

A second statement:

```
update table set field2 = field3, field3 = null from table
where field3 is not null and field2 is null
```

Does the same - and so on:

```
update table set field3 = field4, field4 = null from table
where field4 is not null and field3 is null

update table set field4 = field5, field5 = null from table
where field5 is not null and field4 is null

update table set field5 = field6, field6 = null from table
where field6 is not null and field2 is null
```

So that's 5 statements in total - running them all as a batch will incrementally shift records over by a minimum of one per batch - it will move more per batch in cases where there is an empty space to the left and all the records to the right are adjacent with no gaps. Gaps will tend to move to the right and so I'd guess that by running the batch a minimum of 6 times, you ought to find yourself with a dataset that's conformant with what you want.

The actual sql you need will be dependent on how your RDBMS language deals with nulls or empty strings or whatever, but the good news is you only need 5 statements, and you only need to run them a relatively small number of times.

There's probably cleverer methods than this, but this is fairly simple, and each run of the batch gets you one step closer to where you want to be. On the down-side, it's a bit clunky. If you need to run this periodically, I might be tempted to figure out something a bit more elegant.

Depending on the datasize, it might be worth running something that classifies/counts the number of records you have of each combination/null-count. That way it might be possible to do cut down the number of runs you've got to do - chances are there's only 4 or 5 different patterns, and not the full 64.

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE DATA:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp; 

SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM 
(SELECT NULL TEL1, NULL TEL2, 1 TEL3, NULL TEL4, 2 TEL5,3 TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 TEL1, NULL TEL2,5 TEL3, NULL TEL4, NULL TEL5,NULL TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 TEL1, NULL TEL2,7 TEL3, NULL TEL4, NULL TEL5,NULL TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL TEL1, 8 TEL2,9 TEL3, 10 TEL4, NULL TEL5,NULL TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL TEL1, NULL TEL2,11 TEL3, NULL TEL4, 12 TEL5,NULL TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL TEL1, 13 TEL2,14 TEL3, NULL TEL4, 15 TEL5,NULL TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT 16 TEL1, NULL TEL2,17 TEL3, NULL TEL4, NULL TEL5,18 TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL TEL1, 19 TEL2,20 TEL3, NULL TEL4, NULL TEL5,21 TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT 22 TEL1, NULL TEL2,23 TEL3, NULL TEL4, 24 TEL5,NULL TEL6
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL TEL1, 25 TEL2,26 TEL3, NULL TEL4, NULL TEL5,27 TEL6) AS A 



SELECT * FROM #temp
```

[image]

SOLUTION:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID, 'TEL' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY PHONE) AS VARCHAR) AS PHONE,VALUE FROM 
(SELECT NEWID() AS ID,* FROM #temp) AS P UNPIVOT
(Value FOR Phone IN (TEL1   ,TEL2,  TEL3,   TEL4,   TEL5,   TEL6 )) AS unpvt)

SELECT [TEL1],[TEL2],[TEL3] FROM
(SELECT * FROM CTE) P PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR Phone IN
( [TEL1],[TEL2],[TEL3] )
) AS pvt
```

RESULT:
[image]

Comment: Your query and results may be correct, but using a 1 for every column value makes it hard to be sure the results are ordered in each row like the OP wants.

Comment: @PaulWilliams thanks for the comment. I have changed the values of the sample data to be a bit easier to follow.