# Conditional Mailing Address Re-Formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2012 and have a table for Address with columns

```
Address1, Address2, City, County, PostCode
```

But, column can be empty.

Is it possible to have output like this:

[image]

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the string operations merge and then split as follows:

```
Select
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(merged_addresses), '>>>', '.'), 1)) as address1, 
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(merged_addresses), '>>>', '.'), 2)) as address2,
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(merged_addresses), '>>>', '.'), 3)) as address3, 
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(merged_addresses), '>>>', '.'), 4)) as address4, 
Reverse(ParseName(Replace(Reverse(merged_addresses), '>>>', '.'), 5)) as address5
From
(Select concat(case when address1 is not null then concat(address1,'>>>') end,
              case when address2 is not null then concat(address2,'>>>') end,
              case when address3 is not null then concat(address3,'>>>') end,
              case when address4 is not null then concat(address4,'>>>') end,
              address5) as merged_addresses
  From your_table t) t;
```

I have used `>>>` as delimeter, you can use the delimeter of your choice.

Comment: Hi Popeye, Thank you. It works except the very bottom record (where all column has record) . some how it returning NULL in ALL Field for Row#10 !

Comment: I added and it looks fine. ' IIF(LEN (MailingAddress) - LEN(REPLACE(MailingAddress, '¶', '')) = 4, dbo.PCase([ShipToAddress1]), REVERSE(PARSENAME(REPLACE(REVERSE(MailingAddress), '¶', '.'), 1))) AS address1,'

Comment: [`ParseName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments) states: "If all parts of the object name are qualified, this name can have four parts: the server name, the database name, the schema name, and the object name. ... If any part of the string exceeds 256 bytes, PARSENAME will return NULL for that part as it is not a valid sysname." `select ParseName( 'a.b.c.d.e', 2 );` returns `NULL`, presumably because the _object_name_ parameter has more than four parts, hence the OP's issue with the last row.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is based on a [Martin Smith Answer℠](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44662727/92546) for a similar, but numeric, [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44658834/92546). You'll find an explanation there, and a dbfiddle example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5191c128becabd7f6cd36047a2b164dd).

The changes involve the column names switching from input to results (e.g. `City` to `Address3`), using strings rather than integers, and replacing NULLs in the results with empty strings.

```
select
  Coalesce( OA.Address1, '' ) as Address1,
  Coalesce( OA.Address2, '' ) as Address2,
  Coalesce( OA.Address3, '' ) as Address3,
  Coalesce( OA.Address4, '' ) as Address4,
  Coalesce( OA.Address5, '' ) as Address5
  from @Addresses outer apply (
    select Pvt.*
      from (
        select Address,
          Col = Concat( 'Address', Row_Number() over (order by Idx) )
          from (
            select Address, Idx,
              To_Preserve = Max( IIF( Address = '', 0, 1 ) ) over (order by Idx)
              from ( values
                ( 1, Address1 ), ( 2, Address2 ), ( 3, City ), ( 4, County ), ( 5, PostCode ) ) as V( Idx, Address )
            ) as Unpvt
            where To_Preserve = 1 ) as T 
  pivot ( Max( Address ) for Col in ( Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5 ) ) Pvt
  ) as OA;
```