# Is there a SQL equivalent to the R shift.left function that will shift data in result columns to the left to replace null values?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I am trying to generate a report that shifts data in the columns left by one position on each successive row -- i.e., something that is analogous to the matrix.shift.left in R.

so, I have data in this form:

```
create table sample_data (
    year_month_str char(7),
    month01 int,
    month02  int,
    month03  int
);

insert into sample_data values 
    ('2021-01',49000,25000,24000),
    ('2021-02',null,35000,19000),
    ('2021-03',null,null,34000)
;
```

| year_month_str | month01 | month02 | month03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 49000 | 25000 | 24000 |
| 2021-02 |  | 35000 | 19000 |
| 2021-03 |  |  | 34000 |

I want to get data that looks like this:

| year_month_str | month01 | month02 | month03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01 | 49000 | 25000 | 24000 |
| 2021-02 | 35000 | 19000 |  |
| 2021-03 | 34000 |  |  |

I know I can hard-code a query / CTE / view like this:

```
select
    year_month_str,
    case when year_month_str = '2021-01' then month01
         when year_month_str = '2021-02' then month02
         when year_month_str = '2021-03' then month03
         else null
         end
         as first_month,
    case when year_month_str = '2021-01' then month02
         when year_month_str = '2021-02' then month03
         else null
         end
         as second_month,
    case when year_month_str = '2021-01' then month04
         else null
         end
         as third_month
from 
    sample_data
;
```

but is there a way that can generate this dynamically for an arbitrary number of field and records (assuming there are equal numbers of fields and record -- i.e. it represents a square matrix) other than maybe writing some dynamic SQL?

Comment: There are a couple of previous questions that deal with a similar request  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658834/ms-sql-2012-in-sql-shift-columns-to-left-side-if-column-contains-0   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781309/move-cells-left-in-sql-if-left-contains-null-and-right-contains-value

Comment: @Craig -- yes, the second one will do what I'm trying to do in a much more elegant fashion (and I will probably adapt that) -- Thank you for pointing me to that improved method.  However, the 20781309 method still requires me to know in advance how many columns and rows I have.  I'm still looking for a size-agnostic solution.