# Hana sql move cells left in sql if left contains null and right contains value

Tags: sql, database, hana

I have the same problem which is described in below link, however it has given for sql server but I need solution for Hana db
[move cells left in sql if left contains null and right contains value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781309/move-cells-left-in-sql-if-left-contains-null-and-right-contains-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . In Hana, I think you can `unpivot` using `union all`, then `row_number()` and aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when order = 1 then val end) as a,
       max(case when order = 2 then val end) as b,
       . . .
from (select id, val, row_number() over (partition by id rder by ord) as as
      from ((select 1 as ord, id, a as val from t) union all
            (select 2 as ord, id, b as val from t) union all
            . . . 
           ) t
      where val is not null
     ) t
group by id;
```

Here `id` refers to the columns or groups of columns that uniquely specify each row.

Comment: It worked. Only change i made is, i have applied Partition by ID